# Webform Submission Using Rest API POST method

Tags: 8, forms, webforms

I just created the webform and added fields.

I need to create a Webform Submission Using Rest API POST method. I just installed Rest & Rest UI modules for this.

But when I try to test my API using API tester its showing the error like this :

```
{"message":"Could not determine entity type bundle: \u0022webform_id\u0022 field is missing."}
```

But I have already determined the webform_id and here is my configuration

POST URL : http://example.com/entity/webform_submission?_format=json

**Headers :**

Content-Type : application/json

**POST Data :**

```
{
  "type": {
      "webform_id": "my_form"
    },
"your_mobile":[{"value":"123456789"}],
"your_name":[{"value":"Test"}],
"your_email":[{"value":"test@gmail.com"}]
}
```

Drupal Version : 8.6.4
Webform Module version : 8.x-5.1

Can anyone let me know Why its not working?

Comment: Did you try clear cache? Usually, if an install of the Rest is done after creating a content type error like this popup. It happens to me once when using REST API Post. The only difference, I was not using webform but add a content type the regular way (Drupal form component)

Answer (score 6):

Looking at the examples on the [Webform REST](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rest) project page, you should be using something like…

```
{
  "webform_id": "my_webform",
  "checkboxes_field": [
    "Option 3",
    "Option 5"
   ],
   "integer_field": 3,
   "radio_field": "Mail",
   "email": "myemail@mydomain.com.au"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to enable required services under `/admin/config/services/rest`:

1. Enable REST resource "Webform Submit"
2. Enable REST resource "Webform Elements"
3. Enable REST resource "Webform Submission"